# How To pass two parameter in controller action in cake php?

Tags: cakephp

Only pass the two parameter of controlle in action?

Answer (score 16):

```
mysite.com/myController/myAction/param1/param2
```

in controller:

```
function myAction($arg1,$arg2)
{...}
```

Comment: your answer is good but pass two argument in deferant link..
like i am click the edit link to pass only one parameter( eg. edit_id) and click add link pass another parameter (eg .add_id)

Answer (score 6):

In the view create link.

```
echo $this->Html->link('',array('controller'=>'Vehicles','action'=>'deleteimage',$param1,$param2),array('confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete the image?'));
```

In the above link I have sent two parameters to `deleteimage` function of the `Vehicles` controller.

In controller access the parameters by `public function deleteimage($id, $image)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [named parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/view/541/Named-parameters), like this:

```
example.com/controller/action/param1:value/param2:value
```

In this canse you will find 'param1' and 'param2' in your controller in $this->passedArgs.

You can also define a custom route:

```
Router::connect('/news/:date/:article_name/:id',
    array('controller'=>'articles', 'action'=>'view'),
    array('pass' => array('id'), 'id'=>'[\d]+')
);
```

In this case, the action view in ArticlesController will be called with 'id' as the argument (and the route will only be matched if id passes the check for only containing digits). You can then also access 'date' and 'article_name' in the variable $this->params.